# Handling errors of posix_spawn()

Tags: c, linux

I've found an example code using `posix_spaw()` from [here](https://www.systutorials.com/37124/a-posix_spawn-example-in-c-to-create-child-process-on-linux/).

In that page, `run_cmd()` is defined like below.

```
void run_cmd(char *cmd) {
    ...
    status = posix_spawn(&pid, "/bin/sh", NULL, NULL, argv, environ);
    if (status == 0) {
        printf("Child pid: %i\n", pid);
    } else {
        printf("posix_spawn: %s\n", strerror(status));
    }
}
```

My question is "Is it okay to give return value of `posix_spawn()` to `strerror()` as an argument".

If it is not okay, what would be the best way to handle errors of `posix_spawn()`?

Comment: Did you check [the documentation for `posix_spawn`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_spawn.3.html#RETURN_VALUE)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `posix_spawn()` returns `0` on success and `errno` on failure. So it's OK to pass its result to `strerror`.

According to the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_spawn.3.html#ERRORS):

> The `posix_spawn()` and `posix_spawnp()` functions fail only in the case
>          where the underlying `fork(2)` or `vfork(2)` call fails;  in these cases,
>          these functions return an error number, which will be one of the
>          errors described for `fork(2)` or `vfork(2)`.
>
> In addition, these functions fail if:
>
> `ENOSYS` Function not supported on this system.

Also from the source you can see that it simply returns [`errno`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/spawni.c.html#331).